# How to loop through a list of products and categories on PHP

Tags: php, loops

```
<? 
 $categoriesID = array("popular","old");
 $product => array (
                    Product 1
                    'categoryID' => $categoriesID[1],
                    'Name' => 'Product One',
                    Product 2
                    'categoryID' => $categoriesID[2],
                    'Name' => 'Product Two',
                    Product 3
                    'categoryID' => $categoriesID[2],
                    'Name' => 'Product Two',
                       Product 4
                    'categoryID' => $categoriesID[2],
                    'Name' => 'Product Two',

                   );
```

How can I loop through this to reflect that product 1 belongs to category 1, product 2 belongs to category 2, product 3 belongs to category 2 and so on?

I tried the following but no luck..

```
foreach($product as $key => $pro){
     var_dump($categoriesID[$key]);
 }
```

I would really appreciated any suggestions or how what i'm doing wrong.The goal is to insert the relationship into a database table where in order to insert a product a category_id is required.

Comment: Well, to start with, what you're showing for `$product` is not a valid array

Comment: `$categoriesID[2]` is not defined, as arrays are zero-indexed. So `$categoriesID[0] == 1`  and  `$categoriesID[1] == 2`

Comment: @ Patrick Q  I updated the code. hopefully it makes more sense. it's just an array with categories that have ids. Can you please show me some code? Thank you.

Comment: Now `$categoriesID` isn't a valid array either.  I highly suggest you take an introduction to PHP class/tutorial, as you don't seem to understand basic syntax.

Comment: @ Patrick Q Sir, I know it's not a fully array it's sudo code......... In my example i'm referring to the logic and not the code... If you need me to fix it up I can do that for you but I'm just asking for help on the logic where there are 2 arrays related to a product that's all... it's just logic.

Comment: the definition of $categoriesID is wrong. the word 'popular' and 'old' have to be quoted to be a proper array key. on other hand, the way you're trying to define $categoriesID array makes it associated array, without numeric index, which you are calling in definition of array $product. so either change $categoriesID = array( 1=> 'popular',...) or call its elements like $categoriesID['popular']

Comment: second thought is, in the foreach loop, the $key represents the key of $product array, why are using it to get categories? i think, what you need is $categoriesID[$pro['categoryID']] to have the category name or id, depending on the correct category array definition you will choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your arrays are not written correctly. You got a multi dimensional array here (arrays inside of an array). Read this to understand how they are written and how you can work with them: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

If your categories are numeric you should also consider to use numeric values: 1 instead of '1' inside of the $categoriesID array or depending on the database auto casting capability you will get issues inserting strings as decimals.

Here is your given code modified as working example. Ive changed the var_dump output for better readability of the result.

Ive also changed the array indexes you have used since arrays start at 0. If you need the numbers still to start at 1 you could add some nonsense value at the beginning of the array or subtract 1 when accessing the array. Keep in mind that this is an quick & dirty solution to the given problem.

Nevertheless as Patrick Q said you should consider some introduction to PHP.

```html
<?php

$categoriesID = array('1','2');
$product = array (
    array(
        'categoryID' => $categoriesID[0],
        'Name' => 'Product One',
    ),
    array(
        'categoryID' => $categoriesID[1],
        'Name' => 'Product Two',
    ),
    array(
        'categoryID' => $categoriesID[1],
        'Name' => 'Product Two',
    ),
    array(
        'categoryID' => $categoriesID[1],
        'Name' => 'Product Two',
   )
);

foreach($product as $key => $value){
    echo var_export($value, true) . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could further edit Mariusz's answer to do something like this:

```
foreach($product as $item){
    echo $item['Name'].' - '.$item['categoryID'].'<br>';
}
```

This would give you easy access to both product name and category ID.